# How do i use regex in shell script for replacing capture group content

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Inputs files in multiple directories and want to change the exiting index name to index = windows_pr and index = windows_np.

The WinEventLog blocks shown are all in the same file called inputs.conf but reside in different folder name as A. (EVZ_pr_windows/inputs.conf) and B, (DEG_np_windows/inputs.conf). So any file stanza, with indexes ending _pr will be in folder A inputs.conf whilst, any file stanza with indexes ending _np will be in folder B inputs.conf. The script should change indexes ending _pr to index = windows_pr and indexes ending _np to index = windows_np

WinEventLog blocks in inputs.conf is limited to Application, Security, System, ForwardedEvents, and Setup

I try this but getting error

Below is the error

> ```
> \]_,/s/.*index.*=.*pr$/index = window_pr/' inputs.conf
> ```
>
> sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unterminated address regex

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -E -i '\_\[WinEventLog://(Application|Security|System|ForwardedEvents|Setup)
\]_,/s/.*index.*=.*np$/index = window_np/' inputs.conf

sed -E -i '\_\[WinEventLog://(Application|Security|System|ForwardedEvents|Setup)
\]_,/s/.*index.*=.*pr$/index = window_pr/' inputs.conf


[WinEventLog://Application]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = CNDO_pr

[WinEventLog://Security]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = CGWS_pr

[WinEventLog://System]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = DMRW_pr

[WinEventLog://ForwardedEvents]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = NENP_pr

[WinEventLog://Setup]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = EOFK_pr

[WinEventLog://Application]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = FDWD_np

[WinEventLog://Security]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = ASKD_np

[WinEventLog://System]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = JMSF_np

[WinEventLog://ForwardedEvents]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = JCCD_np

[WinEventLog://Setup]
checkpointInterval = 5
current_only = 0
disabled =0
start_from = oldest
index = HSMS_np
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to achieve and how we can help you.

Comment: please clarify your question. I think it should be `use` instead of `used` .

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error that you are getting and an example that causes the error.

Comment: To try to clarify a bit... Are all of the `WinEventLog` blocks shown supposed to be in the same file called `inputs.conf`, and are you trying to change all of the indexes ending in `_pr` (or `_np`) to `window_pr` (or `window_np`)?

Comment: Exactly, the WinEventLog blocks shown are all in the same file called inputs.conf
but reside in different folder name as A. (EVZ_pr_windows/inputs.conf) and B, (DEG_np_windows/inputs.conf). So any file stanza, with indexes ending _pr  will be in folder A inputs.conf whilst, any file  stanza with indexes ending _np will be in folder B inputs.conf. The script should change indexes ending _pr to index = windows_pr and indexes ending _np to index = windows_np

Comment: The blocks cannot be "in the same file called inputs.conf" while they also "reside in different folder [sic]". Either all of the blocks are in the same file called `inputs.conf` or the blocks are in different files that are each called `inputs.conf` and that reside in different folders. Please indicate which is correct.

Comment: And are the `WinEventLog` blocks in `inputs.conf` limited to `Application`, `Security`, `System`, `ForwardedEvents`, and `Setup`, or are there additional blocks and you're looking to only change the indexes for the explicitly noted blocks?

Comment: Yes, WinEventLog blocks in inputs.conf is limited to Application, Security, System, ForwardedEvents, and Setup

Comment: Still having issues

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error message and assuming that expression #1 begins with `\\_`, char 69 of that expression appears to be `_` immediately following `]`. Consequently, I'd guess that you need a `\` preceeding that `_` to provide a proper terminator for the expression.

Comment: Still could`t resolve the error issues

Comment: Is it still the same error?

Comment: right same error